# How Access components inside NodeInstantiator Delegate?

Tags: qt, qml, qt3d

I have a `line` class in C++ and I want to use it in qml.
I want to draw a line by **mouse** and have **multiple lines**.
In fact, I want to `new` my line class, so I use `NodeInstantiator`.

```
 ListModel {
    id: entityModel

   }
 NodeInstantiator {
    id: instance

    model: entityModel

    delegate: Entity {
        id: sphereEntity

        components: [
            Line { id:lineMesh } ,

            PhongMaterial { id: material; ambient:"red" },

            Transform { id: transform;  }
        ]
    }
}
```

My problem is that I can't use Line Component with its id lineMesh outside NodeInstantiator, and also I don't know how to generate lines and add them to its entityModel.

If I don't use NodeInstantiator , when I draw  lines by left button of mouse and then use Right Button drawing stops. then in the second time , when I use
left button I want New Line Entity .

[image]

As picture shows now I can draw line **just one time .**

Comment: Please edit the post to explain why you need to refer to the `lineMesh`

Comment: I want to use the functions of this component.

Comment: maybe you can reach a function in the delegate using [objectAt](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt3d-core-nodeinstantiator.html#objectAt-method). But then I doni't know if it possible to get to the `lineMesh`

Comment: No, it doesn't work , I test it.

Comment: How about a different idea: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-objectmodel.html ? You will have to do `createComponent`, so a bit more coding

Comment: Do you mean that I don't use NodeInstantiator ?  I cant understand and little confused , NodeInstantiator shouldn't create objects ?

Comment: it might be a stupid idea of me, but I thought maybe you can switch ListModel to ObjectModel and instantiate the Line, PhongMaterial and Transform when you add it to the `entityModel`, in which case you can call the function on the line

Comment: look at this [github example](https://github.com/MASKOR/mapit/blob/e4f67c4da9e28fbf2c26604398e7705803956e7d/tools/gui/qml/ApplicationState.qml) , and [this](https://github.com/MASKOR/mapit/blob/e4f67c4da9e28fbf2c26604398e7705803956e7d/tools/visualization/qml/network/MapitMultiviewNetworkState.qml)  . They say : There is a bug in Qt3D NodeInstantiator: It will crash when used with ObjectModel. Thus, there is an explicit ListModel at the moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Fixed My problem in CPP , which means that I create a class that plays a wrapper role in my program and It is responsible for collecting points .
I `new` my line class here .

**There is a bug in Qt3D NodeInstantiator: It will crash when used with ObjectModel. Thus, there is an explicit ListModel at the moment.**

Answer (score -1):

This is probably not a complete answer, since you question in fact has two questions. But I think it will help you in the end.

In order to draw a line, you need two coordinates. I suggest to store the current coordinate when you click the mouse, and when the next click occurs, make a line from the stored coordinate to the current coordinate (Which probably changed). Then you can add an item to your `ListModel` using the `append` function:

```
MouseArea {

    property var lastPoint : undefined

    onClicked: {
         if(lastPoint === undefined) //first click
         {
             lastPoint = {"x": mouse.x, "y": mouse.y}
         }
         else
         {
             entityModel.append({"startX": lastPoint.x,
                                 "startY": lastPoint.y,
                                 "endX": mouse.x,
                                 "endY": mouse.y});
             lastPoint = undefined
         }
    }
}
```

There are of course variations on this, for example using the `moved` signal on the `MouseArea` to insert entities whenever the mouse moved, as long as the left button is pressed. I'll leave that up to you as an exercise.

Comment: I use qt3d and should use `MouseHandler` instead of `MouseArea` and also I want to use functions that are inside my line component class.

Comment: Ok, then this answer only serves to explain the `append` function ;-)